# Jenkins: Get GIT output into an array

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am currently using the bellow code to get a list of files that were changed between current commit and master branch:

```
        gitOutput = bat script: "git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only HEAD origin/master", returnStdout: true
        changedFiles = gitOutput .split("\n")
        echo changedFiles.toString()
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
[
, D:\home\jenkins\myjob>git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only HEAD origin/master 
, Jenkinsfile, MyData/Program.cs]
```

The output I'd like to get would be:

```
[Jenkinsfile, MyData/Program.cs]
```

I've tried to add .trim() but I'm getting:

```
No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.trim() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

And I'm not sure how to remove the elements that are my command and not the actual output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using:
`listOfFiles[2..-1]` I can drop the first 2 elements and have what I need

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you directly assign the bat command to the variable, which results in your command and its' output being written into the variable.

To avoid this, use:

```
def gitOutput = bat(script: script, returnStdout: true)
```

where the script is the command that needs to be run. This will return only the output and not the command as well.

Comment: I am still getting the same error hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.trim() is applicable for argument types: () values: []